# Flutter :How to trigger screen UI events (e.g incoming call screen) by a long running background service?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement app that receive notification from firebase (fcm) and when received notification start the application to specific screen regardless the app is killed or in background, i try call native code in onBackgroundMessage but no results any help please

```
onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onLaunch: $message");
    printy();
    // TODO optional
  },
  onBackgroundMessage:Platform.isIOS ? null : _backgroundMessageHandler,
  onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
    print("onResume: $message");
    printy();
    // TODO optional
  },
```

Comment: stuck on same situation,have you found any solution?

Comment: no bro please vote the question

Comment: okay, also not found any solution innative agora sdk!

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Create a Notification handler:

```
class NotificationHandler {   GlobalKey<NavigatorState> _navigatorKey; 

NavigatorState get _navigator => _navigatorKey.currentState!;   NotificationHandler(this._navigatorKey) {
    listenNotifications();
        _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
            routeGenerator(routeHome), (route) => false);   }
      void listenNotifications() =>
          NotificationApi.onNotification.stream.listen(onClickedNotification);
      void onClickedNotification(String? payload) {
        //TODO: Access different screens according to the notification information
        _navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil<void>(
            routeGenerator(routeHome), (route) => false);   } }
```

My notification API relevant code:

```
    class NotificationApi {
  static final notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static final onNotification = BehaviorSubject<String?>();
  static notificationDetails() {
    return const NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('protocol', 'protocol channel',
            importance: Importance.max, priority: Priority.max),
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails());
  } ... It continues
```

Then in your App init, initialize it, in my case this line goes after checking the login is correct:

> NotificationHandler(rootNavigatorKey);

Please note this is still under development and testing, I have not yet gone through testing this before initialization, before the app has run at least once, and I am getting some conflicts with my WorkManager which may affect, but I hope it gives you a starting point.